# Javascript error "Cannot set propert 'onmouseover' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have links with a class of "tb-learn-more-link". When I hover over one, I want to display a div with a class of "tb-description" (or in a mobile view..."tb-description-mobile").

When I load my page, javascript is throwing an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onmouseover' of undefined". Also, I'm pretty new to javascript, so if there's a way to do this with fewer lines of code, that'd be helpful.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var e = document.getElementsByClassName('tb-learn-more-link');
  var d = document.getElementsByClassName('tb-description');
  var m = document.getElementsByClassName('tb-description-mobile');

  e[0].onmouseover=function() { d[0].style.display = "inline"; }
  e[1].onmouseover=function() { m[0].style.display = "block"; }
  e[0].onmouseout=function() { d[0].style.display = "none"; }
  e[1].onmouseout=function() { m[0].style.display = "none"; }
});
```

Comment: You're using jQuery, try using that to bind the events.

Comment: easy, your element selectors don't return elements, thus `e[x]` is undefined.

Comment: Though it's wrapped inside a jQuery ready, that's vanilla JS.

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: side-note: `getElementsByClassName` actually has worse support than `querySelectorAll('.some-class');` has... just thought you ought to know...

Comment: another sidenote: You wrapped in in jQuery ready, why don't you use jquery for the rest of the code?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: OMG, you're right. IE8 has `querySelectorAll`, but not `getElementsByClassName`. I never knew that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I've not known that up until a couple of months back... I was gobsmacked, too. but as it would happen, IE8 got one thing right: it implemented the better of the two. But seeing as we've gotten used to IE not jumping on the band wagon that early on, we all seem to assume that MS would've implemented the more old-school looking method

Comment: Whether qSA is really better is debatable... last time I checked `querySelectorAll('.some-class')` was much slower than `getElementsByClassName('some-class')`

Comment: And actually gEBCN is more widely supported than qSA if you consider ancient firefox and opera versions (although I agree IE8 is more relevant than those)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error means that you only have fewer than two elements with the class name `tb-learn-more-link` on the page as of the time that DOM ready code runs. If you have none, it's failing on the `e[0].onmouseover = ...` line because `e[0]` is `undefined`. If you have only two, it's failing on the `e[1].onmouseover = ...` line because `e[1]` is `undefined`.

I'll just point out that as you're using jQuery, you can use it to the full:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Hook the event on `document` but trigger only when it happens on `.tb-learn-more-link`
  $(document)
    .on("mouseover", ".tb-learn-more-link", function(e) {
      if ($(this).index(".tb-learn-more-link") === 0) {
        $(".tb-description").css("display", "inline");
      }
      else {
        $(".tb-description").css("display", "block");
      }
    })
    .on("mouseout", ".tb-learn-more-link", function() {
      $(".tb-description, .tb-description-mobile").css("display", "none");
    });
});
```

That way, it doesn't matter if you add the elements later.

Note that in the above, I'm using `index`, which is a bit crude. If it's possible to navigate from the `.tb-description` element that is being hovered to the relevant things to show, that would be better.

Even better if it can be handled in CSS rather than code (whether it can depends on your markup, how the elements relate to each other), provided you don't need to support IE7 and earlier.

Comment: This is great and mainly works, but you're right that using index is a bit crude as this is now, depending on the view, displaying .tb-description when I want it to be displaying tb-description-mobile. I'm a bit confused by "navigate from the .tb-description element that is being hovered to the relevant things to show". Do you mean navigate from the .tb-learn-more link that is being hovered to the tb-description/.tb-description-mobile items to show? How would I do that?

Comment: I changed it a bit and have it working by changing the else statement to" else { $(".tb-description-mobile").css("display", "block");. This still relies the number of elements not changing though.

Comment: *"I'm a bit confused by "navigate from the..."* The elements in the page are arranged in a bit tree, called the DOM. (You probably knew that.) With the handlers above, `this` within the handler will refer to the DOM element in question. So depending on your DOM structure, it may be that you can put a jQuery wrapper around it (`$(this)`) and then use methods like [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest), [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find), [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextall), [`prevAll`](http://api.jquery.com/prevall), and such to find the appropriate element to show/hide.